# I am new to linux/ubuntu and would like to install a driver for my printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a file called linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz and would like to install that driver and then install my printer with that driver. Any idea of what I need to do? This is my first time using linux. I've tried the tar zxvf command but that did not work. I have the IP address of my printer.

Comment: You can use Archive Manager to extract it

Comment: What is the make and model of the printer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the instructions Brother supplies after you click the download button? I have had no issues with them.

[image]

The only thing I would mention that the official instructions do not is that I would move the file to a different directory before running these commands. The last time I ran them it created an uninstall script and other stuff you might want to keep. (also because you run the installer as root you can't really delete them anyways, unless you run the uninstaller as root or delete them manually as root from the terminal)

Comment: pastethese commands into a terminal; ..  so copy the hight-lighted areas to paste right-click at the text prompt  copy these commands and paste them into the terminal; one by one and hit the ENTER key after each paste `cd Downloads` .. if that is where the file is .. then `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz` and then `sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1` and that will run the installer script it will find your printer and ask you if that is the one you mean .. and you can say yes .. and later it will find the ip address and see you are happy with that too